# Is it possible incorporate a Stage into a primaryStage javaFX?

Tags: javafx, openscenegraph

I need to pass to a native method the handle of a javaFX window on which to render a world made with OSG (Open Scene Graph).

I understood that on javaFX only the Stage has this native handle, all the other objects, for example Nodes and Pane do not have a native handle.

So I thought, if it were possible to insert the Stage (for native rendering) and javafx widgets into the primary Stage, I would have the possibility to manage different levels, so that I could superimpose javaFX objects on the OSG rendering.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: no, you can't insert anything (except a scene) into a stage ..

Comment: you can have a different transparent stage over JavaFX one for your native rendering. But you will need to take a special care about mouse, keyboard, and window events.